# How to create GKE private cluster with Jinja Template?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I'm trying to write a Jinja template and a bash script to create a private GKE cluster with an option (in my bash script) to give it access to **private AND public endpoints**.

So I want my bash script to make this cluster with private endpoint access by default and when the user runs with a flag (deployment.sh --public-endpoint) to make it with public endpoint access.

This is what my Jinja template looks like:

```
resources:
- name: {{ CLUSTER_NAME }}
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    cluster:
      name: {{ CLUSTER_NAME }}
      description: Customer Stack Cluster 
      network: {{properties["network"]}}
      subnetwork: {{properties["subnetwork"]}}
      *privateClusterConfig:
        enablePrivateNodes: true
        enablePrivateEndpoint: true
        **{% if --public-endpoint flag was passed %}
             <p> Make it with a public endpoint access </p>
        {% else %}
             <p> make it with private endpoint access </p>
        {% endif %}***
        # Configure the IP range for the hosted master network
        masterIpv4CidrBlock: 172.16.0.32/28
      ipAllocationPolicy:
        useIpAliases: true
      nodePools: 
        - name: nodepool
          config: 
            oauthScopes:
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
            machineType: n1-standard-2
            # Default will be passed in 
            serviceAccount: {{ properties['computeServiceAccount'] }}
          autoscaling: 
            enabled: true 
            minNodeCount: 2
            maxNodeCount: 5
          initialNodeCount: 2
```

That part of my bash script looks like this:

```
CLUSTER=$(gcloud deployment-manager deployments create "${NAME}" --template deployment.jinja --properties "region:${REGION},zone:${ZONE},network:${NETWORK},subnetwork:${SUBNETWORK},computeServiceAccount:${COMPUTE_SA},k8sVersion:\"${K8S_VERSION}\"" --format=json)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then error "FAILED_DEPLOY_GKE"; fi
```

I don't know how to make this work and how the if statement syntax is in Jinja.

Comment: If you want to provide outbound internet access for certain private nodes, you can use Cloud NAT or manage your own NAT gateway. Please check [private clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept)
So it may make more sense to separate the different deployments in two different files, because in case of using the public endpoint you may have to set up Cloud NAT or own NAT gateway as well.

Comment: "because in case of using the public endpoint you may have to set up Cloud NAT or own NAT gateway as well" - you mean private endpoint?

Comment: Yes you are right, setting Cloud NAT gateway as a private endpoint. You may find this better explained in [Private Google Access Interaction](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-pga)

Answer (score 0):

To add the condition to your script,you may find useful the next two alternatives for each access to the private cluster, one with no client access to the public endpoint and the other with limited access to the public endpoint.

[Creating a private cluster with no client access to the public endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#private_cp)

To create a cluster without a publicly-reachable control plane, specify the `enablePrivateEndpoint: true` field in the `privateClusterConfig` resource.

When creating a private cluster using this configuration, you can choose to use an automatically generated subnet, or a custom subnet.

Find the documentation related to [Creating a private cluster with limited access to the public endpoint API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#auto_subnet)

For the automatically generated subnet, specify the `privateClusterConfig` field in the Cluster API resource:

```
{
  "name": "private-cluster-1",
  ...
  "ipAllocationPolicy": {
    "createSubnetwork": true,
  },
  ...
    "privateClusterConfig" {
      "enablePrivateNodes": boolean # Creates nodes with internal IP addresses only
      "enablePrivateEndpoint": boolean # false creates a cluster control plane with a publicly-reachable endpoint
      "masterIpv4CidrBlock": string # CIDR block for the cluster control plane
      "privateEndpoint": string # Output only
      "publicEndpoint": string # Output only
  }
}
```

Or a [custom subnet](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#custom_subnet) which may be a little bit more complex

Please share the script if you success, it will very helpful to the community.